# AutoHotkey sending odd characters

Tags: autohotkey

I have this autohotkey script:

```
StringCaseSense, On
^'::
{
 Input, char, L1
   if char = a
      Send á
   else if char = A
      Send Á
   else if char = e
      Send é
   else if char = E
      Send É
   else if char = i
      Send í
   else if char = I
      Send Í
   else if char = o
      Send ó
   else if char = O
      Send Ó
   else if char = u
      Send ú
   else if char = U
      Send Ú
   else
      Send %char% ;ignores ctrl+' is if it isn't followed by any of aeioucyAEIOUCY
   return
}
```

However, when I press ctrl + ', then a (for example), it inserts Ã¡ (with the upside down ¡). However, the script says it's supposed to insert an á. Why does it do this?

Comment: Are you using the unicode version of AutoHotkey and did you save your script as UTF-8? See http://ahkscript.org/docs/Scripts.htm#cp

Answer (score 0):

This may be a Unicode/UTF-8 issue and/or something else.

Trying looking up `virtual key` in the AHK help topics.

You can probably replace the characters you're trying to send with Unicode equivalents to fix this... i.e.,

```
Send {U+00FA}      ; Send ú
```

You can look for virtual key codes either in the key history of the script via the tray icon and then View menu, or just look up the Unicode number by running the windows `charmap` utility and the Unicode hex key will be shown in the bottom left.